# What causes red flashes in Kdenlive rendering output?

Tags: kdenlive

In the output of my video there is a short sequence where the whole video is solid red, with some corrupted text visible near the bottom. As usual in video editing software, this probably marks corrupted or missing frames. But why does it happen?

This happens in a location in the video where I put a Kdenlive Title Clip below a still image with a Fade Out effect. It does not happen with all possible combinations of rendering settings. In my case, it happens in a MP4 HD 1920×1080 project if setting it to be scaled to 1280×720 in the rendering settings and with output quality set to 26.

Kdenlive 19.12.3 under Ubuntu Linux 20.04 here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this could be the problem, but I got that exact rendering error from a similar scenario. I had title clips with fades as you describe, but they were on a video track that was above an empty gap in a lower video track. I just made a dummy clip to go beneath and fill that gap, and it cleared up the rendering error.

also, I had version 21.12.3 on Ubuntu 19.10 with the parallel processing on ( by default, didn't know it was an option) and encoder threads 0, also default. Since using a dummy clip was all it took to solve my issue, it means that the parallel processing bug has been fixed for 21.12.3 at least.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue in that newer version. When you switch parallel processing off, does that fix the issue for you?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my original answer a bit awkwardly. Changed it to describe that the parallel processing is NOT an issue for 21.12.3 at least.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use **effects that are not compatible with parallel processing**. Disable "Parallel processing" in the render options and try again. Also make sure that "Threads" in the render options is set to "0", to choose the number of threads automatically. Otherwise parallel processing might still be done (though I doubt it).

Notably, somebody already reported this issue with the very same video project content:

> Switching off parallel processing solved my other problems (corrupt frames (flashes) when using titles with the fade effect and black rectangle). ([source](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=272&t=165297#p433021))

Also to note, in Kdenlive version 20.08 there is a commit that marks the "Parallel processing" feature as experimental in the UI ("[Render widget: avoid misuse of parallel processing](https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive/commit/a155503)").

**If somebody can conform this issue in the latest Kdenlive release, please tell.** Because then we can [report this as a bug](https://kdenlive.org/en/bug-reports/).